# Show continuity of norm over multiplication on a field

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, field-theory, normed-spaces

I'm trying to show that the norm of a product on a field is continuous, but am unable to determine how.

For any norm $\left\|\cdot\right\|$ on some field $F$, show that for any $\epsilon\gt0$ there exists $\delta\gt0$ such that $\|x-x'\|\lt\delta$ and $\|y-y'\|\lt\delta$ imply that $\|xy-x'y'\|\lt\epsilon$.

Is this supposed to be point-wise continuous or uniformly continuous? I believe I can show point-wise continuity but not the latter.

Comment: What you ask to prove is that the multiplication of a field is continuous in the norm topology (if the field has a norm, obviously), *not* that the norm is a continuous function over multiplication, which is a nonsensical statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly won't be uniformly continuous.

Use
$$\|x'y'-xy\|\le\|x'y'-x'y\|+\|x'y-xy\|\le\|x'\|\|y'-y\|+\|y\|\|x'-x\|.$$

Comment: Makes sense. That's what I did, but I thought I was missing something.