# Issues with norm function on fields

Tags: number-theory

Let be a field that comes with a norm $\| \cdot \|$. Now I would like to show the following are continuous with respect to the norm:

(i) the function $F\times F\to F$ defined by $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$,

(ii) the function $F\times F\to F$ defined by $(x,y)\mapsto xy$,

(iii) the function $F\to F$ defined by $x\mapsto x^{-1}$, and

(iv) the function $F\to F$ defined by $x\mapsto -x$.

I was able to show (i) and (iv) very easily as I was able to create a "$\delta$ without it being dependent on points". What I mean by that is the following: say to prove (ii), I started with $x,y\in F$ and $\varepsilon>0$. We have to find a $\delta$ such that whenever $\| x-x' \|<\delta$ and $\| y-y' \|<\delta$ one obtains $\| xy-x'y' \|<\varepsilon$. I used the idea that $$\| xy-x'y' \|=\|x(y-y')+y'(x-x') \|\le \| x \|\| y-y' \|+\| y' \| \| x-x'\|\le \| x \|\| y-y' \|+(\|y\|+\|y-y'\|) \| x-x'\|.$$ But at this stage I am not sure what would be an appropriate $\delta$. Of course I cannot involve $x'$ or $y'$ in the definition of $\delta$. So I am not sure what to do here. Similar problem show up in (iii).

Similar discussion can be found here [Show continuity of norm over multiplication on a field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2303656/show-continuity-of-norm-over-multiplication-on-a-field). However, the answer does not suggest any way. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: You are already on the right track. Now use $\lVert y'\rVert \leq \lVert y'-y\rVert + \lVert y\rVert$

Comment: I did use that. But I am not sure how it fits in.

Comment: If you apply it to $\lVert x\rVert \lVert y-y'\rVert + \lVert y \rVert \lVert x-x'\rVert$ then you get a sum of three terms. Now you can choose $\delta$ independent of $x'$ and $y'$ to bound this sum by $\varepsilon$.
Note that $\delta$ may depend on $x$ and/or $y$!

Comment: I understand. But is it possible to explicitly write this $\delta$?

Comment: You can find an explicit formula for $\delta$ in terms of $x$, $y$ and $\varepsilon$, yes. For example, choose $\delta$ such that each of the three terms is less than $\varepsilon/3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the hint by @GraffL one can choose $\delta$ to be (at most) the minimum element of the set $\{\frac{\varepsilon}{3\|x\|},\frac{\varepsilon}{3\|y\|},\sqrt{\frac{\varepsilon}{3}}\}$.